# changing hidden input - python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I want to change the hidden input in the website:

[image: the website]

using playwright. It seems to have changed but when I print the related section seems nothing is selected. I need help. Thanks.

```
def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()

page = context.new_page()

page.goto("https://www.shopier.com/ShowProductNew/products.php?id=12617395")
r = requests.get(page.url)

page.locator('select[name="selectFirstVariationGroup\[\]"]').select_option(value='182695')

page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')
page.wait_for_timeout(4000)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

select_tag = soup.find_all("select", {'type':'hidden'})
print(select_tag)
```

Output (selected one is None:"Seciniz"):

```
    [<select class="custom-select btn-block" id="selectFirstVariationGroup" name="selectFirstVariationGroup[]" onchange="singleVariationFirstVariationClick(this)"> 

<option selected="" value="-1">Seçiniz</option>
<option value="182693">M</option>
<option value="182694">L</option>
<option value="182695">XL</option>
<option value="182696">XXL</option> </select>]
```

Comment: The hidden input field is unrelated to the `<select>` tag.  If you want to change what's in the combo box, then you need to change the `selected` attribute in the `<option>` tags.

Comment: I don't get the point. In playwright request I did it like you said and it works. But when printout using bs4 it seems nothing selected.

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  You are fetching the HTML of the page using `requests`, which has zero relationship to the active page in your Firefox instance.  You modified the DOM in Firefox.  That doesn't change the page as stored on the server.

Comment: what will change can you suggest what should I use ?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I get the point now. And solved. Thank you so much!